# How to Redirect Some URL's to index page in PHP

Tags: php

I have to do some maintenance of one angular project  which has a PHP backend.
I have never worked on PHP so I am trying to locate how URL's are configured in PHP project.
I just want to redirect /careers and /apply to index page currently it gives me page not found.

Simply I want to change the url from /apply to #/apply and server the index.php file

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to those pages using php?

Comment: this is because you need to add .php to the url, if you want a clean url like /careers instead of /careers.php you need to use a .htaccess file

Comment: How are you trying to redirect? Also, if you've never done PHP, you shouldn't be working on it. The security risks are big.

Answer (score 2):

You are using angularjs so routing is also best option for you.Please check this link it might be helpful.

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

and if you want in php only then

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

there are different ways also but it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy way to redirect:

```
header("Location: index");
die();
```

That line of code sends a HTTP header to the client to tell it to redirect. To do this, just put this code at the top of your PHP file:

```
<?php
  header("Location: index.php");
  die();
?>
```

---

> so I am trying to locate how URL's are configured in PHP project

Simply put, they work very similarly to how HTML files are setup. When you load `www.example.com/index.php`, there's a PHP file called `index.php` in the root of where the webpage is stored.

You can also do redirects with `.htaccess` files/other config files so it'll be `www.example.com/index`, but that's not inside PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is easier to achieve with .htaccess:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/apply/$ http://domain.tld/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/careers/$ http://domain.tld/`

Comment: i want to change /apply to #/apply how can i do that and server index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to add .php to the url (/careers.php), if you want to have clean url's like `/careers` instead of `/careers.php` you need to use a `.htaccess` file with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

or

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: okay let me simplify how can i change url from /apply to #/apply

Comment: Everything depends on how the server implements the routing system: you cannot assume that such files exist.